# Filter dataframe using startswith twice

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to filter using startswith twice. Something like this

```
df = df.loc[df['Col'].str.startswith('Foo', na=False) | df['Col'].str.startswith('Bar', na=False)]
```

But this not work, how can I fix?

Comment: In what way does it not work exactly? (seems to work on a mocked up DF that's `df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['Foo', 'Foobar', 'Bob', 'Bar', 'Barstool']})`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem. The first is to use paranthesis:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Col'].str.startswith('Foo', na=False)) | (df['Col'].str.startswith('Bar', na=False))]
```

The second is to make use of the string startswith method, that can take any number of arguments:

```
df.loc[df['Col'].str.startswith(('foo', 'bar'))]
```

Comment: The first option worked.